# How to use Tiled Map Editor to realize perspective projection in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-x, perspective, world-map

I want to use tiled map editor in cocos2d to create a world map 1080 * 1080; and the effect is the more far away, smaller buildings. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I add a camera to realize it.